# How to POST a XDomainRequest call to a WCF service method with parameters

Tags: ajax, wcf, xdomainrequest

I think I've read every StackOverflow post on XDomainRequest and another few dozen on AJAX and WCF, but I'm still having trouble getting an **XDomainRequest AJAX call** to work.  I've implemented CORS ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin") on my WCF service and my code works fine with xmlHttpRequest in Chrome and Firefox, but I'm making calls cross-domain and so for IE I need to use the XDomainRequest object.  My xdr works fine when I GET or POST to a method that has no args, and I can even use the GET verb successfully to a method with args using a querystring, but when I try to **POST** to a method **with args** my xdr throws an error, even though I put a breakpoint in the BeginRequest method and I see that the Response from the server is "200 OK".  I'd like to think I've tried every combination of config file settings but I have to be missing something.  Any help in pointing me in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Here are the pertinent parts of my code:

**WCF - Global.asax**

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //for CORS
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    }
```

**WCF - IService1.cs**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST")]
    string GetData();

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST")]
    string GetData2(string param);
}
```

**WCF - Service1.svc**

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string GetData()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }

    public string GetData2(string param)
    {
        return string.Format("Hello - {0}", param);

    }
}
```

**WCF - Web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="WcfService1.Service1Behavior" name="WcfService1.Service1">
            <endpoint address="AjaxEndpoint" behaviorConfiguration="AjaxBehavior" contract="WcfService1.IService1" bindingConfiguration="AjaxBinding"/> 
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="WcfService1.Service1Behavior">
                <!--<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />-->
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="AjaxBehavior">
                <enableWebScript/>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
        <webHttpBinding>
            <binding name="AjaxBinding"/>
        </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

**Client AJAX call**

```
var WcfURL = "http://localhost/WcfService1/Service1.svc/AjaxEndpoint"
if (window.XDomainRequest) {
//IE - use cross-domain request
xdr = new XDomainRequest();
xdr.onprogress = function () { alert("onprogress: " + xdr.responseText) };
xdr.onload = function () { updateText(xdr.responseText) }; 
xdr.onerror = function () { alert("xdr error") };
xdr.timeout = 7500;
xdr.ontimeout = function () { alert("xdr timeout") };

var data = "passedInParam";
//var method = "/GetData";  //this works
var method = "/GetData2";  //this throws an error
xdr.open("POST", WcfURL + method);

xdr.send(data);
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the solution.  Thanks to Fiddler, I was able to view more of the response I was getting back from the service.  The error was

> The incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'. The
>   expected message formats for the operation are 'Xml', 'Json'. This can
>   be because a WebContentTypeMapper has not been configured on the
>   binding.

Armed with this information I started looking into the WebContentTypeMapper.  I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038673/wcf-input-huge-xml-as-stream-with-content-type-xml-text) article useful, and after adding the WebContentTypeMapper method I was able to see that the contentType of my request coming from the XDomainRequest was of type "application/json" (as expected) when I did **not** include an argument in the XDomainRequest.send() method, but changed to type "application/octet-stream" when an argument was passed in. (ie. xdr.send(data))  I don't know why it changes to octet-stream, but in doing so it would cause the service method to throw a 500 error (with the message from above) and therefore cause the xdr request to error.  But the WebContentTypeMapper is aptly named and using it to change the contentType is easy enough.  After correcting it to type Json my xdr is working well.

Here's the method:

```
public class CustomContentTypeMapper : WebContentTypeMapper
{
    public override WebContentFormat GetMessageFormatForContentType(string contentType)
    {
        if (contentType == "application/octet-stream")
        {
            return WebContentFormat.Json;
        }
        else
        {
            return WebContentFormat.Default;
        }
    }
}
```

And here are the portions of the config file that were updated:

```
<endpoint address="AjaxEndpoint" behaviorConfiguration="AjaxBehaviour" contract="WcfService1.IService1" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomMapper"/>
...
<bindings>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="CustomMapper">
                <webMessageEncoding webContentTypeMapperType="WcfService1.CustomContentTypeMapper, WcfService1" />
                <httpTransport manualAddressing="true" />
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
    </bindings>
```

Comment: This was a great explanation which I have not manage to find in such a simplified way. Thanks!

Comment: When I tried POST using XDomainRequest, I also got the same issue about 'WebContentTypeMapper'. When I plugged in MDK1969's above solution, I got rid of the error but I still get HTTP 404 Method not found error. Please help!

Comment: Actually I noticed "EndPoint Not Found" error in Fiddler. Below is my endpoints in service.

 <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="web" contract="ItemService.IItemSerivce"/>
<endpoint address="ValidateRequest" behaviorConfiguration="web" contract="ItemService.IItemSerivce" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomMapper"/>

Comment: I found a problem in my web.config when i compared my config with above config settings. It is working now. This post was really helpful. Thanks!