# Contains an unrecognized http body format value 'Xml'

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, web-config, wcf-configuration

There are a number of similar questions on stack overflow, but none have helped me formulate a solution.

Question below is the closest, but I couldn't get it to work and my other services stopped working when I tried to implement it.

[WCF input huge XML as Stream with Content-Type: xml/text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038673/wcf-input-huge-xml-as-stream-with-content-type-xml-text)

> Error: Incoming message for operation 'IncomingXML' (contract ... with namespace ...) contains an unrecognized http body format value 'Xml'. The expected body format value is 'Raw'. This can be because a WebContentTypeMapper has not been configured on the binding. See the documentation of WebContentTypeMapper for more details.

Basically I need this and only this web service to accept "application/xml".  At the moment it accepts only "raw", the service fails when the call has "application/xml" set.

The problem is two parts, one allow the service to accept xml and two, don't effect the other web services.  This is the only service that accepts incoming xml.

Does anyone have any suggestions? If I can't get this to work without disrupting the other web services.

Contract

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST")]
void IncomingXML(Stream xml);
```

Service

```
public void IncomingXML(Stream xml)
{
}
```

Web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <extensions>
        ...
    </extensions>
    <diagnostics>
        ...
    </diagnostics>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="jsonEndpointBehavior">
                <webHttp helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" defaultBodyStyle="WrappedRequest" faultExceptionEnabled="true" />
                <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
                <endpointDiscovery enabled="true" />
            </behavior>
            <behavior name="xmlEndpointBehavior">
                <webHttp helpEnabled="false" defaultBodyStyle="WrappedRequest" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Xml" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" faultExceptionEnabled="true" />
                <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
            </behavior>
            <behavior name="rawEndpointBehavior">
                <webHttp helpEnabled="false" defaultBodyStyle="WrappedRequest" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" faultExceptionEnabled="true" />
                <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
        <webHttpBinding>
            <binding name="jsonBinding" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
            <binding name="jsonsBinding" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true">
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                </security>
            </binding>
            <binding name="xmlBinding" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
            <binding name="xmlsBinding" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true">
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                </security>
            </binding>
            <binding name="rawBinding" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
            <binding name="rawsBinding" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true">
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </webHttpBinding>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="soapBinding" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior" name="Namespace.Web.WCF.Service">
            <endpoint address="json" behaviorConfiguration="jsonEndpointBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="jsonBinding" name="jsonHttpEndpoint" bindingName="Namespace.Service.JsonHttp" contract="Namespace.Web.WCF.IService" />
            <endpoint address="json" behaviorConfiguration="jsonEndpointBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="jsonsBinding" name="jsonHttpsEndpoint" bindingName="Namespace.Service.JsonHttps" contract="Namespace.Web.WCF.IService" />
            <endpoint address="xml" behaviorConfiguration="xmlEndpointBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="xmlBinding" name="xmlHttpEndpoint" bindingName="Namespace.Service.XmlHttp" contract="Namespace.Web.WCF.IService" />
            <endpoint address="xml" behaviorConfiguration="xmlEndpointBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="xmlsBinding" name="xmlHttpsEndpoint" bindingName="Namespace.Service.XmlHttps" contract="Namespace.Web.WCF.IService" />
            <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="xmlEndpointBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="rawBinding" name="rawHttpEndpoint" bindingName="Namespace.Service.RawHttp" contract="Namespace.Web.WCF.IService" />
            <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="xmlEndpointBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="rawsBinding" name="rawHttpsEndpoint" bindingName="Namespace.Service.RawHttps" contract="Namespace.Web.WCF.IService" />

            <endpoint address="web" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingName="Namespace.Service" contract="Namespace.Web.WCF.IService" />
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
```

Answer (score 1):

This blog post has the solution: http://kimcuhoang.blogspot.be/2011/04/solving-raw-issue-with-wcf-and-content_13.html

Basically you have to override the default web message encoding

Create a custom mapper:

```
public class RawContentTypeMapper : WebContentTypeMapper
{
    public override WebContentFormat GetMessageFormatForContentType(string contentType)
    {
        if (contentType.Contains("text/xml") || contentType.Contains("application/xml"))
        {
            return WebContentFormat.Raw;
        }
        else
        {
            return WebContentFormat.Default;
        }
    }
}
```

Then refer to it in the binding configuration:

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="NotificationServiceBehavior" name="AtlanticGateway.GatewayComponent.Services.NotificationService">

<endpoint behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="RawReceiveCapable" contract="AtlanticGateway.GatewayComponent.Message.INotificationService" />


<bindings>
 <customBinding>
   <binding name="RawReceiveCapable">

     <webMessageEncoding  webContentTypeMapperType="AtlanticGateway.GatewayComponent.RawContentTypeMapper, AtlanticGateway.GatewayComponent, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />

     <httpTransport manualAddressing="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="524288000" transferMode="Streamed" />
     ...
```